# Generic NHibernate Linq select with func

Tags: .net, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I am attempting to do a generic select on a nhibernate object.  I am passing a Func into a get method...

```
T Get(Func<T, bool> selectQuery)
{
    using (var session = SessionFactory.Session.OpenSession())
    {
        return (from x in session.Query<T>() where selectQuery(x) select x).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

But when this method executes, I am receiving the following error:

> "Unable to cast object of type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlParameter' to type 'NHibernate.Hql.Ast.HqlBooleanExpression'."

I have attempted to use an expression instead, but get the same error.  I am missing something fundemental or is what I am trying not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't validate it now but I guess the problem is that instead of passing the expression tree, you are passing the delegate. Try this one:

```
T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> selectQuery)
{
  using (var session = SessionFactory.Session.OpenSession())
  {
      return (from x in session.Query<T>() where selectQuery(x) select x).FirstOrDefault();
  }
}
```

(I hope it compiles with no errors, don't have the compiler at hand)

Comment: I swore I had tried it before, but I must have had something a little different. Your example does not compile, but a slight change made it work...
    
                return (from x in session.Query<T>() select x).Where(selectQuery).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: One question I have though is if this still does the where portion as delayed execution until the FirstOrDefault occurs. I'll have to check the logs to see what is generated.